# anime.js - how to call animation from multiple buttons (same class)

Tags: javascript, anime.js

I'm trying to call an `anime.js` animation with a play button. the documentation explains how to play animation only with a single button (`querySelector`), but I need to play the same animation from different buttons.

I unsuccessfully tried to write a function with `querySelectorAll` instead of a single `querySlector`:

```
 var animation = anime({
  targets: '.reds',
  translateX: ['-100%', '100%'],
  duration: 1600,
  easing: 'easeInOutQuad',
  autoplay: false,
});

var oks = document.querySelectorAll(".correct");

for(x=0; x<oks.length; x++){
    var ok = oks[x];
  ok.addEventListener("click", function(){
    animation.play;
  });
}
```

The `anime.js` documentation goes like this:

```
var animation = anime({
  targets: '.play-pause-demo .el',
  translateX: 270,
  delay: function(el, i) { return i * 100; },
  direction: 'alternate',
  loop: true,
  autoplay: false,
  easing: 'easeInOutSine'
});

document.querySelector('.play-pause-demo .play').onclick = animation.play;
document.querySelector('.play-pause-demo .pause').onclick = animation.pause;
```

Does anyone have an idea how to use a class to run the same animation from multiple elements? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent some times to read the documentation and It seems that you have to use loop through all your element and you need to attach `onclick` event.

Here is working sample **to run the same animation from multiple elements:**

```js
var animation = anime({
            targets: '.play-pause-demo',
            translateX: 270,
            delay: function (el, i) { return i * 100; },
            direction: 'alternate',
            loop: true,
            autoplay: false,
            easing: 'easeInOutSine'
        });


document.querySelectorAll(".correct").forEach((el)=> el.onclick = animation.play);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.1/anime.min.js" ></script>

    <button class="correct">btn 1</button>
    <button class="correct">btn 2</button>
    <button class="correct">btn 3</button>
    <button class="correct">btn 4</button>
    <button class="correct">btn 5</button>

    <div class="play-pause-demo">this is div</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Alireza for the reply but my question was referring to the element that triggers the animation and not the target (document.querySelector('.play-pause-demo .play').onclick = animation.play;)

Comment: Tahnks again Alireza - I understand what you say but Unfortunately it's not working. I tried also to apply this 'animation.play' to a specific element targeted via 'getElementById' but it didn't work neither. It works only when I use the querySelector method - therefore I thought it's an anime.js issue

Comment: I updated my answer and I put my code as snippet for you please check it again.

Comment: Thank you It works! - I guess I didn't write the loop correctly